# URL encoding seems to get in the way of properly json encoding/decoding in my PHP program

Tags: php, json, http, urlencode, simpletest

I'm implementing a PHP script which receives an HTTP POST message with in the body a json string, tied to a 'report' parameter. So HTTP POST report=.
I'm testing this out with SimpleTest (PHP Unit Testing).

I build the json:

```
$array = array("type" => "start"); // DEBUG
$report = json_encode($array);
```

I send the POST:

```
$this->post(LOCAL_URL, array("report"=>$json));
```

(calls a method in the WebTestCase class from SimpleTest).

SimpleTest says it sends this:

```
POST /Receiver/web/report.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: close
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

report=%7B%22type%22%3A%22start%22%7D
```

I receive as such:

```
$report = $_POST['report'];    
$logger->debug("Content of the report parameter: $report");    
$json = json_decode($report);
```

The debug statement above gives me:

```
Content of the report parameter: {\"type\":\"start\"}
```

And when I decode, it gives the error

```
Syntax error, malformed JSON
```

The 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content-type is automatically selected by SimpleTest. When I set it to 'application/json', my PHP script doesn't see any parameters and as such, can't find the 'report' variable.
I suppose something is going wrong with the url encoding, but I'm lost here as to how I should get the json accross.

Also, what is the usual practice here? Does one use the key/value approach even if you just send an entire json body? Or can I just dump the json string in the body of the HTTP POST and read it out somehow? (I had no success in actually reading it out without a variable to point to).

Anyway, I hope the problem is somewhat clearly stated. 
Thanks a bunch in advance.

Dieter

Comment: The problem was indeed the magic quotes, apparently it's enabled by default on my version of MAMP.
If I send it now as a key/value pair (the json being the value), and without defining a content-type, it works like a charm. 
Can't use the content type application/json however, but I guess that the reason for this is that I'm violating some RFC kind of stuff, which I explicitly don't want to do.
Thanks a bunch @johncartwright and @hakre for your awesome help!

Comment: Tip: Select on of the answers as "the answer", e.g. John's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have magic quotes enabled (which is a big no-no). I would suggest you disable this, otherwise, run all your input through stripslashes().

However, it is better practice to reference the POST data as a key/value pair, otherwise you will have to read the php://input stream.

Answer (score 2):

For the quick fix, try:

```
$report = stripslashes($_POST['report']);
```

Better, [disable magic quotes GPC](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). G=Get, P=Post, C=Cookie.

In your case *Post*. Post values get automatically ("magic") quoted with a single slash.

Read [here how to disable magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).